# Current firmware version is not supported to update via kies

Tags: updates, samsung-kies, device-firmware, samsung-captivate-glide

I've got Samsung captivate glide. It comes with at&t only so I've got unlocked version. Its base firmware version is 2.3.5 Ginger Bread. Official update of ICS 4.0.4 is out by at&t and Samsung. Thre is whole good tutorial for How do I update my Samsung Captivate Glide to Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich? 
Heres the reference link of it: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/SupportOwnersFAQPopup.do?faq_id=FAQ00048593&fm_seq=53023

I've installed Samsung Kies version 2.5.313043 on my Windows 7 32-bit desktop PC. As soon as I connected my Samsung captivate glide to my PC via micro-USB cable Samsung Kies detects it and says
 `Your device's current firmware version is not supported to update firmware via Kies`.
`Current firmware version : PDA:KI3 /PHONE:KL1 /CSC:KI3 (ATT)`
 
(See attached screenshot) [image]Although there is an official update released I cannot understand why my device can't update via Kies?? Can any one tell me how to update my phone??

Any link or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance....

Comment: You might want to check the [odin tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info) plus [heimdall tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/heimdall/info) for alternative update tools.